# Why aren't all the cookies set to HTTPONLY and SECURE

Tags: http, cookies, https

As the title says, why aren't all the cookies out there `HTTPONLY` and `SECURE` set to `True`?
What are the benefits of having cookies which do not operate under these terms.

Thanks

Akimba

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are used to store temporary data. You can save device specific preferences of a user in a cookie, if you will set the `HTTPONLY` flag to true you won't be able to set this data and retrieve it using JavaScript.

The `SECURE` flag informs the browser that cookie should only be transported over a HTTPS connection. In development environments where you are developing a website on localhost this cannot be always true. Also there are sites where HTTPS connection is not required, but user preference for example theme is stored in cookies.